# Cluster Sampling involving Design Effect

Tags: sample-size, cluster-sample

A survey of residents is performed using cluster sampling. The design effect is 3.00. From the survey, the estimated proportion of people who are happy with their insurance company is 0.42 with a standard error of 0.05. How many people were in the sample?

Can someone please explain as to how I am to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.